# How to make a form submit return the correct result using AJAX & JSON?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I've been going through the jQuery course on CodeSchool and seem to be stuck on my own project. I'm working on a basic dependent drop down menu and when I hit the submit button, I want a specified object to load. However, my error message on my AJAX request comes up.

What I've noticed is that if I don't specify my dataType as JSON, my object loads. However, my success callback comes back as "Car: undefined Price:undefined..."

Most of my code can be found here: http://cdpn.io/bozie

I was unable to attach my AJAX result page.

Please help

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer the question accurately. You should post just relevant code snippets here or a link to something like jsfiddle. Also, needed would be snippets that handle the server-side response, which we can't see from the link provided.

Comment: If I were to throw out a guess however, I'd guess that your server isn't sending the response as mime type JSON, even if the response text is in JSON format. That could cause the discrepancy where your object could fail to load if specified as JSON, but would load if not specified and possibly result in undefined data. But that's a wild shot in the dark.

Comment: My code is displayed if you click "Edit this Pen" at the bottom of the page. It's pretty much the same as jsfiddle. Thanks for your help. Can you help me determine my problem with the new info provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE: Malformed JSON in AJAX response

The [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/) requires that your property names and string values be wrapped in double quotes. For example:

```
{
    "Car": "2012 Chevrolet Avalanche",
    "Price": "$10,999",
    "Features": "Soft seats!"
}
```

According to the [jQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), when specifying `dataType: 'json'` the "JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any *malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown*."

### Areas of concern in your code

#### Your AJAX request URL should be a server-side page

<strike>Looking at your code, I see that you're sending your AJAX request to `modelsTest.html`. I'd have to see the code on that page to give you an accurate answer, but I suspect that because you're sending your request to an HTML page, but specifying the JSON dataType, that will cause confusion; by default HTML pages return only HTML-type data.</strike>

Typically, your AJAX request is sent to a server-side scripted page for processing. For example: `modelsTest.php`, `modelsTest.asp`, etc. or some REST API route to a server-side controller such as `/api/modelsTest/`

Your server can return data of any type if you set the response headers manually, or jQuery can make its best guess if your server-side script doesn't specify a MIME-type in the response header; just don't specify a `dataType` in your AJAX properties.

UPDATE: For a static test like this, putting JSON in an HTML file is acceptable if you're specifying `dataType: 'json'`. jQuery will not get confused; instead, it will override the default HTML response header and parse the contents as JSON. However, you could also just put your static response in a .json file if your server supports this MIME-type.

#### Simplify your test

UPDATE: In your additional info, you indicate that you're not actually utilizing the drop-down menus at this point; and you expect only a static JSON response from your AJAX request.

For the purpose of your static test, I recommend not including the drop-dwon menus at this point, as they are superfluous and confusing (for you *and* me), if not actually being used. It's also helpful, when troubleshooting, to strip out other superfluous script and just focus on the task at hand. Here is your AJAX test, simplified:

```
<button type="submit">Test AJAX Response</button>
<div class="response"></div>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $.ajax('modelsTest.html', {
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('.response').html(
                    $('<p></p>')
                    .append('Car: ' + data.Car + '<br>')
                    .append('Price: ' + data.Price + '<br>')
                    .append('Features: ' + data.Features)
                );
            },
            error: function(data) {
                $('.response').html(
                    "<p>We're sorry, but our vehicle didn't load. Call us for availability.</p>"
                );
            }

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

#### Serialize your form data, pass it all at once

When you're ready to start passing data to a server-side page for processing, a good and simple way to pass form data is to serialize it.

In your example, you're passing only one variable in your AJAX request:

```
data: {"vehicle": $('#vehicle').val()},
```

So, your form-processing page (`modelsTest.html` or server-side equivalent) is only receiving partial data and may not be able to complete whatever functions it needs to return the correct JSON response.

Typically, you'd serialize the entire form and pass all of it at once:

```
data: $('#inv_selection form').serialize(),
```

Now your form-processing page (`modelsTest.html` or server-side equivalent) has all of the form data to use as necessary.

#### Basic dependent drop-down menu setup

Also, worth mentioning, but not <strike>likely</strike> a cause of the AJAX response error, is that you mentioned that you're working on a basic dependent drop-down menu. The select menus in your example aren't dependent on each other.

Typically, a dependent menu setup requires that the user make a selection from the first menu before the second menu becomes populated with options relevant only to the parent menu.

In your case, the user would have to make a selection from the *Make* menu, before the *Model* menu is even populated. The *Model* menu should be visible, but *disabled* until it is populated with relevant options based on the selection from the *Make* menu.

This is achieved by using javascript to listen for a *change* event on the parent menu (*Make*), which calls a function that queries a local array or object with the *Models* relevant to the selected *Make* or sends its own AJAX request to get the options array or object.

> *NOTE:* The *Year* menu may or may not be a prerequisite to the *Make* menu. If not every make is available for all of the years listed, then *Make* should be dependent on the user's selection for *Year*.

A good example of a dependent drop-down menu using local variable data, no AJAX required:
[Select Box Change Dependent Options dynamically](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/select-box-change-dependent-options-dynamically)

Now that you know how to do AJAX, you could just as easily do an AJAX request to a server-side page to get the dependent menu options, instead of using locally hard-coded variables.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Next time, you should simply update your original question with any additional info. Posting additional info as an answer may lead to confusion for others either attempting to answer your question or seeking an answer for a similar problem. With the new info you provided, I should be able to answer what's causing the error response and undefined JSON properties. I'll simply update my above answer, since all of it still applies.

Comment: Thanks a bunch gfullam. I finally made my vehicle appear when I click the submit button. However, what I noticed is that I receive my response regardless of what(or if a) value is selected in the final drop-down menu. What I can do in my result page is to create an array with multiple vehicles, but how can I make the drop down menu select the specified vehicle contained in that array?

Comment: I suspected you'd run into this, which is why I included a section in my answer about using a server-side page to process the form data. An answer would be outside the scope of this discussion, but your next step is to learn some server-side language (PHP, ASP, etc.) and get access to a server which supports it, or set up a localhost on your machine that supports the language you choose (the latter is worth doing, if just for the experience). I recommend starting with PHP because the resources are abundant and a large community exists on stackoverflow and at large to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

@gfullam, that's for your detailed answer. The following is the only content of my modelsTest.html page:

{
    Car: 2012 Chevrolet Avalanche,
    Price: '$10,999',
    Features: 'Soft seats!'
}

Do I have to specify what type of content it is on that page or change the file extension? The reason it's not under a php or other server-side extension is because I haven't gotten to the point of php/ruby/python, etc.

I forgot to mention that I'm working backwards with the dependent drop down menu. I want to figure out how to return a specified object in a results page first, then how to make the drop down menus dependent. I still don't know how to do that either so if you could point me in the right direction, that would be very helpful. :)